Finding the maximum number of acute interior angles in a 2001-gon

This is a question I found online. With the limited research I was able to do, I was only able to find that a convex polygon can have a maximum of 3 acute interior angles, but in this case the polygon can also be concave.
Looking at cases in smaller polygons, I believe the answer would be either 1334 or 1335; 2001 is not possible, (as far as I am aware) and 667, 1001 are most likely too little.
I know that the polygon must be concave, so It must have reflex angles, and using that I am trying to make constructions for smaller sided polygons but I haven't really gotten anywhere. Any help is appreciated.

You're right, one of $1334$ or $1335$ is the answer. By a slight modification of this question you can construct a polygon with one of those many number of acute angles. That will rule out $667$ and $1001$. $2001$ is ruled out by a sum of angle counting argument.

Constructing a polygon with 2001 sides and 1334 acute angles is easy. I don't know if 1335 is also possible.
